# Is there a way to call constructor with class instance pointer?

Tags: c++

We can call destructor explicitly through class pointer, why not constructor? Any idea?

```
#include <iostream>

class Con {
public:
    Con( int x ) : x( x ) {

    }

private:
    int x;
};

int main() {
    Con* c = new Con( 1 );
    //c->Con( 2 ); //illegal
    c->~Con(); // ok!
    delete c;
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: `c->~Con();` may be ok, but `delete c;` on the next line is not, as it will attempt to call the same destructor again.

Comment: You're calling the destructor through the _object pointer_.  Not the class pointer.

Comment: As xtofl said above you are calling the destructor using object pointer. But if you have not used the constructor you have no object that points to the constructor.

Comment: @xtofl: Thanks, my bad! It should be object pointers.

Comment: @Cubbi: Thanks. I was sloppy when adding the `c->~Con()`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No. You cannot.

```
Con* c = new Con( 1 );
//c->Con( 2 ); //illegal
```

You've already called the constructor in the `new` expression.

By the time you've a valid pointer of type `Con*`, you've already created an object. And calling *constructor* on the "constructed" object doesn't even make sense. So why would C++ allow that?

Comment: This might be nice, but it is not right: It is not that you cannot call the constructor, but rather that the syntax for executing the constructor is special *placement-new*: `new (c) Con(1);`.

Comment: @David: What isn't right? You don't call the constructor on the object. You're "constructing" another object in the same memory currently occupied by `c`. That is no much different than `new` expression itself.

Comment: Let's say that it is *imprecise*, as the question probably is, and lets word it in a different way: *you can execute the constructor over an already constructed object*, and it will be UB if the object does exists, in the same way that calling the destructor on an already destructed object is an error: `Con c; c.~Con(); c.~Con();`. That is if you use *call the destructor* to represent *destroy*, then you may as well say *call the constructor* to represent *construct*, and that is done with `new` (including placement new)

Comment: I understand the question not on the *should do* or *is correct*, but rather on the *the syntax allows/does not allow*, and in that sense a slightly different syntax does allow you to execute the constructor manually on a pointer to a type, as you can execute the destructor manually. And in both cases there are good uses and bad uses of the syntax (there is an example in the C++0x drafts that actually tells you to manually call the destructor and reconstruct in place when dealing with unions for which different members might have non-trivial constructor/destructors)

Answer (score 21):

You can actually call it, it is just that the syntax is not that of calling a member method (of which the destructor is an special case), so it is not done with the *member access* operators. Rather you have to resort to the *placement-new* syntax:

```
Con c;
c.~Con();        // destroy, now c is not a Con anymore
new (&c) Con();  // recreate, now c is a Con again
```

As a particular case, in the C++0x proposal, that is actually used in one of the code examples, providing means to reuse a `union` as a different type in the event of an union containing non-POD elements:

```
union U {
   int i;
   float f;
   std::string s;
};

int main() {
   U u;
   new (&u.s) std::string( "foo" );
   u.s.~string();
   u.i = 5;
}
```

}

Comment: Somewhat of a warning: I've noticed this might overwrite existing data that isn't set in the constructor. That is, if you allocate the pointer, set variables that shouldn't be set by the constructor, and call _placement-new_ the variables that shouldn't have been changed may have changed. I noticed `__memset_avx2_unaligned_erms` overwriting something it shouldn't have.

Answer (score 3):

It will be easier for you if you don't think of constructor and destructor as a functions, that you call. You don't call them. You can only construct or destruct an object. And, as a part of constructing, constructor body is executed. Same, as a part of object destruction, destructor body is executed.

So you can construct object on the stack

```
YourClass variable(constructor_arguments);
```

and it will be destructed automatically when it's out of scope.

You can also create object on the heap

```
YourClass * ptr = new YourClass(parameters);
```

To destruct such an object you use operator `delete`

```
delete ptr;
```

You can also construct an object in some memory you provided by yourself (rarely needed)

```
char * pool = new char[sizeof(YourClass)]
YourClass *ptr = new(pool) YourClass(parameters);
```

You destruct such an object explicitely and the syntax looks like function invokation, but it's rather an object destruction

```
ptr->~YourClass();
```

After this line your object is no more. Invoking anything on it is an undefined behavior. And you still have to manage the memory you allocated for this object

```
delete[] pool;
```

So, your question means 'Why can I explicitely destruct an object to which I have a pointer but I can't construct it'? You can't, because it is already constructed.

You can also read [C++ FAQ Lite explanation](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.10)

Answer (score 1):

You can only call the constructor when the object is **being constructed**, hence it's name.  Once the object is constructed, I see no reason why you'd want to call it again on the same object.  If you want to do something then, you need to call a function defined in that class.

Comment: You can actually call the constructor, just not with the member access semantics, but rather using *placement-new* (the whole purpose of the `void*` version of placement new is providing means to *create* an object in place, i.e. execute the constructor on a block of memory)

Comment: @David, thx! I'm not advanced enough to have known that  yet :)

Answer (score 1):

A Constructor's intent is to be called when the object is created.  Nothing else.  If you had a reference counter to keep track of the number of objects, allowing the constructor to be called as a function would mess the counter up.

If you want to reinitialize or reset an object, you can add a function called Reset() or Initialize() and call it from the constructor.  Then, you can also call Reset() or Initialize() from an object pointer.

Answer (score 0):

No you cant call the constructor of a class the way you explained, and that's because, c doesn't point to a valid object of con type.

Answer (score 0):

Ofc you can call it from an object instance , see this code :

```
 #include <iostream>
class foo{
      public :
      int foo_var;
      foo(){
            std::cout<<"foo_var = "<<foo_var<<std::endl;
            }
      };
int main()
{
    foo * f = new foo();
    // set foo_var
    f->foo_var = 10;
    // call constructor by passing object instanse
    foo * f1 = new(f) foo;
    std::cout<<(f==f1)<<std::endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

the second output is "foo_var = 10" so it is working . the third output is "true" then (f==f1) that mean the constructor does not allocate new memory (the operator new does , but we passed a pointer to it so he wont alloc an other) 
there you are a really usefull practice :

```
#include <iostream>
template <class t>
class smart_pointer{
      t * p; // the real normal pointer
      public :
      smart_pointer()
      {
          p = (t*) malloc(sizeof(t)); // allocate memory 
          try{ 
          new (p) t; // call the constructor 
          } catch (...)  // if it throws any exception
          {
                  free(p); // free p , dont use delete , because it will
                  // call the destroctor calling the destructor will cause 
                  // freeing a not allocated memory that causes a crash
                  throw; // throw the exception what ever it was
          }

      }
      ~smart_pointer(){delete p;}
      t operator = (t val) // assigment operator
      {
               *p = val;
               return val;
      }
      operator t(){ // type casting operator , usually for std::cout
               return *p;
               }
      };
int main()
{
    smart_pointer<int> x;
    x = 10;
    std::cout<<x<<std::endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

it is recommended  to read "effective c++" , "more effective c++" , "effective modern c++" books